# What happens to Kubernetes state when all EKS worker nodes are deleted or go down at the same time?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a Amazon EKS cluster with a bunch of applications and resources deployed to it. I now want to delete and recreate all worker nodes at once.

Will my deployed applications loose their state in this case or will they be recreated as they were (preserving their state in ETCD on the control plane) when the new worker nodes start?

I'm especially interested whether the state of my ingresses and secrets will be preserved during the moment when there are no worker nodes available at all, only to be recreated again when the new nodes come up?

For example I'm using sealed-secrets to encrypt all of my secrets. Will I have to re-encrypt all secrets or will the sealed-secrets-controller (running in the kube-system namespace on a worker node) keep it's state when all node go down at once?

I wonder the same in regard to the aws-load-balancer-controller which manages all ingresses? If it looses all of its pods and is then recreated on the new nodes, will the state of the ingress be preserver and will the new loadbalancer controller continue to manage the already existing ingresses?

Answer (score 0):

Your state will be maintained.
EKS/k8s uses etcd to store all the data required for the state, and everything related to Kubernetes objects, be it ingress, secrets or deployments.

Same with aws-load-balancer-controller, it will manage all ingresses because this data is not stored on worker nodes. It is held in etcd, and in the case of AWS-EKS, it is not accessible to anyone apart from the master.

Make sure, you delete and recreate only the worker nodes, if you delete the cluster, everything will be destroyed.